# How to input without newline in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simple file editor in Python via the console (called PyCons). Here is my current program:

```
def PyCons(f):
  file = open(f, "r")
  appe = open(f, "a")
  print("\n=====\nPyCons Editor, v1.2\nPython 3.6.1\n")
  global i
  i = 0
  for line in file:
    i += 1
    print(" {}|  ".format(i) + line, end='')
  for k in range(10000000000000):
    print("\n {}| ".format(i+1), end='')
    inp = input("")
    if inp == "@PyCons.save()":
      print("\n=====")
      break
    else:
      i += 1
      appe.write("\n" + inp)
```

I used the `end` method to make sure that the existing code in the file was printed properly in its line format, but the `input` function does not have an `end` attribute. So, when I go to enter code in the editor:

```
PyCons("magic.html")    
...

=====
PyCons Editor, v1.2
Python 3.6.1

 1|  <p>Hello!</p>
 2|  <h1>Big text!</h1>
 3|  <h2>Smaller text!</h2>
#Should be no spaces here
 4|  <p>More stuff!</p>
#No spaces here either
 5|  @PyCons.save()

=====
```

...I get those big, nasty spaces between my inputs. Does anybody know a way to suppress the output of this space, similar to the `end=''` method used for the `print function`?

EDIT: Project location for reference: https://repl.it/@xMikee/File-Editing

Comment: `inp = input("").strip('\n')` should do the trick

Comment: Its not clear, but I think his issue might be that newlines are being printed in the terminal, not just the output OP writes to disk.  If so-  don't pass input a string, call it as `input()` instead of `input("")`, that might fix your issue.

Comment: @lenik That did not do anything, unfortunately.

Comment: @DillonDavis That did not work, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newlines from the inputs are just local echos from the console. You see them on your screen but they aren't actually returned by the `input` function.

The real problem is with the newline you explicitly print before every line number. Remove the `\n` so the line that prints line numbers becomes:

```
print(" {}| ".format(i+1), end='')
```

Furthermore, the file you're loading may not necessarily have a trailing newline in the end, so you need to detect that and print a newline if that's the case. Note what I added after your first `for` loop:

```
def PyCons(f):
    file = open(f, "r")
    appe = open(f, "a")
    print("\n=====\nPyCons Editor, v1.2\nPython 3.6.1\n")
    global i
    i = 0
    for line in file:
        i += 1
        print(" {}| ".format(i) + line, end='')
    if not line.endswith('\n'):
        print()
    for k in range(10000000000000):
        print(" {}| ".format(i+1), end='')
        inp = input("")
        if inp == "@PyCons.save()":
            print("\n=====")
            break
        else:
            i += 1
            appe.write("\n" + inp)
```

Comment: That does not work because of my usage of `end=''` (it makes it so the new input is on the same line as the previous one).

Comment: That actually works. I tried your code with this change myself. Did you try it?

Comment: Maybe insert a `print("")` between for loops, then remove the newline?

Comment: @connectyourcharger Well, why did you print a `\n` before every line number in the first place anyway?

Comment: @blhsing Because if I don't, this happens:  `4|  <p>More stuff!</p>  5|` because I put the print's `end` to `''`

Comment: @connectyourcharger But your keyboard input gives you the newlines locally when you type and hit Enter, so you don't need to print newlines from the code.

Comment: @blhsing Using `end=''` on the print statement technically puts the start of the "new line" at the end of the old one.

Comment: @connectyourcharger The point is you are letting the user type a newline as input after displaying a line number as a prompt, so when the user sees ` 3| ` as a prompt and types `<h2>Smaller text!</h2>` and then hits *Enter*, the Enter key he hits will bring the cursor to a new line because of local echo.

Comment: @blhsing Could you provide a link to your edited program that works?

Comment: @connectyourcharger My edited program is nothing more than removing `\n` from your `print("\n {}| ".format(i+1), end='')` line. But now I realize what your problem might be. The file you load may not have a trailing newline in the end, so you need to print a new line yourself if that's the case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174091/discussion-between-connectyourcharger-and-blhsing).

Comment: @connectyourcharger I just edited my answer with the suggestion I just made to account for the lack of a trailing new line in the file you're loading. Give it a try then.